# Artifactory won't load with blocked HTTPS outbound

Tags: artifactory, firewall, offline

I have Artifactory Pro (trial) installed on VM in Azure. I have to check how will it work without internet access. I use only Maven repositories so I created NSG outbound role for blocking HTTPS access. After reboot Artifactory won't load. From log:

> 2023-01-04T11:27:40.641Z [jfrou] [WARN ] [0e5f4bf9d6dc7f57] [local_topology.go:274         ] [main                ] [] - Readiness test failed with the following error: "required node services are missing or unhealthy"
> 2023-01-04T11:27:41.087Z 35[jfob ] [INFO ] [44efcd4b59cba041] [artifactory_client.go:159     ] [main                ] [] - Fetching Artifactory version [artifactory_client]
> 2023-01-04T11:27:41.092Z 35[jfob ] [INFO ] [44efcd4b59cba041] [artifactory_client.go:176     ] [main                ] [] - Got HTTP 503 from Artifactory [artifactory_client]
> 2023-01-04T11:27:41.092Z 35[jfob ] [INFO ] [44efcd4b59cba041] [artifactory_client.go:183     ] [main                ] [] - Fetch base URL from Artifactory returned: 503 <!--
> ~ Artifactory is a binaries repository manager.

Comment: Why dont you allow it to communicate outbound? This sound fishy. More like you try to bypass the licensing stuff.

Comment: @marc this is not a helpful comment. Moreover the requirement is a valid usecase for many security conscious companies and licenses don't require the internet to enforce themselves.

Comment: @VivekKodira There are enough services that require a internet connection to work properly and check the license state with a online service. And OP did not state why want/need to block it. Perhaps this is a xy problem.

Comment: Thanks to all. The issue was in Azure VM default security